# how is a diff pathspec defined

Tags: git, diff

In [gitdiffcore(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitdiffcore.html) it simply states:

```
The pathspecs are used to limit the world diff operates in. 
They remove the filepairs outside the specified sets of pathnames. 
E.g. If the input set of filepairs included:

    :100644 100644 bcd1234... 0123456... M junkfile
```

My question is how to read this, i.e. which fields are which, and what should they represent?

I'm looking so that I can understand if there is any mileage in detecting pathname changes (as an option) separately from the file rename detection which is both expensive and tends to suggest to users that many files have been renamed (rather than a single path change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's break this down:

```
:100644        100644         bcd1234...     0123456...     M         junkfile
old file mode  new file mode  old file hash  new file hash  modified  file name
```

---

to create archives with a given name from a directory at a specified commit, use the [`git archive` command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html):

```
git archive --prefix='your_product_v1.2/' -o 'your_product.zip' v1.2:path/to/directory/
```

assuming, you want to create an archive from `path/to/directory/` as it was in version `v.1` (tag, branch, you can even use a commit id here). the archive will be named `your_product.zip` (format inferred from file name, `.tar` is also possible), and all files will be placed in the subfolder `your_product_v1.2` inside the zip file.

this way you don't have to rename the directory inside your VCS (why would you do that anyways?). hope that helps! leave a comment if things are still unclear.

Comment: and.. `M` tells you the file was modified. a move is represented by `R` (rename) – knittl. (just joining the bits together)

Comment: @philip: yes, that's why i wrote `M` and below of it `modified`. your question read like you don't care about renames because they give some kind of wrong impression about path changes. i didn't fully understand what you meant ;)

Comment: Actually I was looking the otherway around... We have a common work flow that will rename the top level directory with version info then zip the directory. This would mean that Git (diff) >thinks< that we have renamed every file! I'm trying to get folks to use Git, but that workflow issue makes it awkward....

Comment: @philip: there were a few patches once to "hide bulk renames", but it never made it to master (it isn't in next or pu anymore even). so it isn't too easy. if i might ask: why do you rename directories with version info? that sounds awkward to me. do you have the version number as part of the directory name? there are better way to do that, let me extend my answer

Comment: It's a legacy local process issue. As an easy local management method folks have a TLD which is their version number/name, which they zip and store. When the code reaches some 'point' the code below the TLD is then copied to the "big" corporate VCS (loads of paperwork ;-). I'm trying to get Git used in that space between the corporate VCS and the code hack level, and I need to 'cope' with such TLD renames if I'm to make Git a workable reality. Hope that explains my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 numbers are the file group rights flags. The second 2 are the before and after sha1 indicators. The M tells you that it's a modification. The last is your file name.

Comment: `M` tells you the file was modified. a move is represented by `R` (rename)

Comment: Thank you to @knittl and @adymitruk for that explanation